# Transformar código jQuery em JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Eu tenho um problema parecido com o desse : [Inserir texto - Stack](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/28152/mover-texto-para-uma-box/28176#28176)

Mas no meu caso eu preciso do código em JavaScript puro e não tenho a menor idéia (novato em prog. web) de como mudar do jQuery que deram como resposta.

jQuery:

```
$('.botao_add').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().children('select').append($('<option>', {
    value: $(this).parent().children('input:first').val(),
    text: $(this).parent().children('input:first').val()}));
});

$('.botao_del').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().children('select').children('option:selected').each(function() {
        $(this).remove();
    });
});
```

Como esse trecho ficaria em JavaScript puro? E como verificar de alguma maneira, mesmo em jQuery, se o dado inserido no input já foi inserido na box?

Comment: Não acho o certo alguém te dar o código pronto, o mais legal seria você aprender o JS e conseguir fazer por si só. De uma estudada em JS no Codeacademy, é super interativo e fácil. Depois de 30 minutos você já vai conseguir fazer seu próprio código. http://www.codecademy.com/pt/tracks/javascript

Comment: Se estou aqui perguntando, é porque não tive progresso no que estou desenvolvendo mesmo tendo um pouco de conhecimento em `javascript` (bem pouco)! E não acho errado alguém querer pegar um código pronto para se ter uma base!

Comment: O site [You Might Not Need jQuery](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/) contém informações sobre como fazer muitas coisas com Javascript puro. Tem um slider para você escolher se quer ver a versão IE8+, IE9+ ou IE10+

Comment: Depois que conheci o jquery não quero nem ver js puro na minha frente, no tópico que você citou tem alguns exemplos em js puro, e você pode notar que é muito mais complicado, mas o que te impede exatamente de usar o jquery?

Comment: @Jader oque me impede de usar o jquery é o meu superior, pois ele acha que é uma forma muito "complexa"!

Comment: Estou meio sem tempo para fazer isso agora, mas a primeira coisa que eu perguntaria, caso pudesse te ajudar, seria: precisa de compatibilidade com browsers legados, ou pode ser HTML5? Com HTML5 fica bem fácil fazer muitas coisas do jQuery.

Comment: Nesse caso em que estou trabalhando @RuiPimentel, necessitaria de compatibilidade! Mas obrigado mesmo assim!

Comment: @Jader, nesse caso do JQuery que você implementou, tem a possibilidade de verificar se o valor no input já foi inserido dentro da box?

Comment: @Jader Não é o caso do Bruno, mas o desempenho do Javascript puro é bem (por exemplo, [veja esta comparação](http://jsperf.com/javascript-hasclass-versus-jquery)) superior ao jQuery.

Comment: @Beterraba Eu já estava ciente desta diferença de performance, mas para aplicações simples, e até mesmo muitas vezes mais complexas, isso não afeta em absolutamente nada... Ela só vai aparecer em um loop com muitas repetições onde um seletor for utilizado.

Comment: @Bruno eu tinha respondido com o código jquery com verificação de existência (conforme consta no seu pedido), mas estavam negativando minha resposta então eu a removi, segue o jsfiddle para você dar uma olhada: http://jsfiddle.net/jaderw/ht5b9xzk/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma maneira mais simples para o seu problema:

```
function move(Origem, Destino)
{
    var opt = document.createElement("option"); 
    var valor = Origem.value;
    if(valor==""){
        alert("Informe um dado válido!"); 
        return;
    }

    opt.text = valor ;
    opt.value = valor ;
    Destino.options.add(opt);
 }

function tira(Destino)
{
    var i;
    for(i = 0; i < Destino.options.length; i++)
    { 
        if (Destino.options[i].selected && Destino.options[i].value != "")
        {
            valor=Destino.options[i].value;
            Destino.remove(Destino.selectedIndex);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Considerando que:

1. O próprio jQuery, pelo menos na versão 2, não oferece suporte aos browsers ***bem*** antigos;
2. O IE6, IE7 e até o IE8 estão cada dia mais raros;
3. O trabalho para tornar o código ***realmente*** compatível com estas relíquias exige uma boa dose de trabalho, que pode ser inclusive bem instrutivo para você;

Eu apresento a "tradução" a seguir, que testei apenas no Chrome. O objetivo foi apenas transcrever, literalmente, instrução por instrução do jQuery para um JavaScript simples. Resolvi não utilizar recursos das versões mais recentes, como o `querySelector` e o `querySelectorAll`, e também não me preocupei em otimizar nem validar nada. Com o código em mãos, você poderá, então, estudar os bugs que ocorram nos browsers em que você testar e, então, editar a resposta com as soluções.

```
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
    var botoes_add = document.getElementsByClassName("botao_add");
    for(var i = 0; i < botoes_add.length; i++){
        botoes_add[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
            var selects = this.parentElement.getElementsByTagName("select");
            var input_first = this.parentElement.getElementsByTagName("input")[0];
            for(var j = 0; j < selects.length; j++){
                var novo_option = document.createElement("option");
                novo_option.value = input_first.value;
                novo_option.innerHTML = input_first.value;
                selects[j].appendChild(novo_option);
            }
        });
    }
    var botoes_del = document.getElementsByClassName("botao_del");
    for(var i = 0; i < botoes_del.length; i++){
        botoes_del[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
            var selects = this.parentElement.getElementsByTagName("select");
            for(var j = 0; j < selects.length; j++){
                var options = selects[j].getElementsByTagName("option");
                for(var k = 0; k < selects[j].children.length; k++){
                    if(selects[j].children[k].selected) selects[j].removeChild(selects[j].children[k]);
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Pelo menos no Chrome 36.0.1985.125 para Linux, no qual testei, tenho certeza que a funcionalidade é ***idêntica*** ao [jsFiddle que você citou](http://jsfiddle.net/jaderw/ht5b9xzk/).

Edit: esqueci de colocar [o meu pŕoprio jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ruipimentel/trLnbmur/2/), e de dizer que o `innerHTML` foi escolhido ao invés do `innerText` para permitir a compatibilidade com o Firefox.

Espero que sirva como um primeiro passo para você.

Abraços!

Comment: +1 pelo esforço que você colocou nesse post. Adoraria dar outro +1 pelo comentário sobre ser instrutivo.

Comment: Valeu, @Renan! Tendo algo para acrescentar ou percebendo algum deslize, não só você como todo mundo, pode se sentir livre para editar :D

Answer (score 0):

acho q se tu baixar a versão de desenvolvimento do jquery e pesquisar o que faz cada função tu consegue entender, até porque jquery é feito em puro js, ele é apenas uma biblioteca enorme com varias funções.

Exemplo de um código "nao jquery" que simula o seletor *`$`* jquery em js puro.

**html**

```
<p id="ha">lalala</p>
```

**js**

```
function $(par) {
    re = /^[.#]/;
    if (re.test(par)) {
        return document.querySelector(par);
    } else {
        return document.querySelectorAll(par);
    }
}

console.log($("#ha").id);
```

ou

```
(function (window) {
    function $(par) {
        re = /^[.#]/;
        if (re.test(par)) {
            return document.querySelector(par);
        } else {
            return document.querySelectorAll(par);
        }
    }

    window.$ = $;
})(window);

console.log($("#ha").id);
```

**output**

```
ha
```